# Can't access Filezilla SSL/TLS from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, ftp

I have setup a Filezilla FTP server. Using a normal connection I can add the "ftp://192.168.x.x" in windows 7 and mapped like a local drive.
Now I have used SSL/TLS on the FileZilla Server, but the clients can only login to the FTP server from the Filezilla Client GUI and not directly from Windows 7. I want to map the network location of "ftpes://192.168.x.x" in Windows 7. Is there any way I can map the network location to the clients. So the clients no need to use Filezilla Client GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry not possible with native windows FTP only direct FTP connections are possible using explorer, for SSL/TLS you will require a client.

Comment: Just to expand a little you can get tools to 'enhance' explorer to add more features, google a tool I use called expandrive